# Coded UI Test recording not working when clicking on link

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I am using the code generator for Coded UI Test by recording the actions and I have a problem and a few questions:

#### Problem

The problem I am having is that I am trying to record a test. I go to a main page and click a link. The problem is that this specific link "*crashes*" Visual Studio. Whenever I click it using IE it stops working for a while, then after a few seconds the recorder prints this message: `Last mouse action was not recorded`.

This link works when I'm not recording, and the recording works with Chrome. But it does not when I'm recordgin with IE. I realised that there is something different about this link, it looks like this on the source:

```
...
<a href="/login"></a>
...
```

While the other links have something inside the `<a>` tags. Is that the reason? Why does it work when not recording and it does not when recording?

**[I am on a Windows 2008 with Visual Studio 2013]**

#### Questions

1. How am I supposed to use these Coded UI Tests? One `CodedUITest.cs` for each functionality or several related tests in one file?
2. Is it possible to pass a `browser` as a parameter (i.e. IExplorer, Chrome) so a test can be run in that browser? I am able to run a test in with the same code in different browsers by:

   `...`

   `BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";`

   `UIMap.CheckMainPage();`

   `...`

   What I am asking is if there is a way to run a test like `CheckMainPage("Chrome")` instead of writin a new method.

Answer (score 0):

since codedui test methods cannot get parameters you have two options to cset the desired browser:

1. use Data Driven tests - this will multiple your test for each row in your data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx
2. read the values from a config file (so you could change the browser without changing the code)

to my knowledge the recorder only works with IE but the test can run on different browsers. (see attached link to MSDN)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx

as to why the recorder fails on that specific link - more information is needed - but perhaps the lack of any unique identifiers preventss the recorder from loaction and recognising the link (if possible add an Id attribute to the a tag and retry).